# Error trying to deploy Attribute Groups in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, attribute-group

I have an Attribute Group created at the Parent level BU based on DEs that exist in a Shared Data Extension folder which is shared with each child BU.
I've created a snapshot of the Attribute Group but when I try to deploy it in the Child BU, I get an error on every single line of the deployment package.  The DE components of the package just give a generic error (and yes, I've tried recreating the snapshot several times) and the Attribute Sets fail with a message that the DEs were not deployed.
[image]

Part of the challenge (?) is that the DE's used here are already available from within the child BU (in the shared data extension folder) - but I'm not sure what else I can do in this situation

Comment: If the Data Extension already exists (as it sounds like it is via shared folder), it will error when trying to create the data extension again as it is already there.